# Is there a Java web framework that allows the user to create custom fields (like in Mantis bugtracker)?

Tags: java, frameworks

Is there a Java web framework that allows 
the user to create custom fields, like in Mantis bugtracker?

http://www.mantisbt.org/wiki/doku.php/mantisbt:features

Here's what I actually want to do:

Allow the user to create a template / form that has several custom fields
(textboxes, checkboxes, comboboxes, etc.)

Once a template has been created (of which several others can also be made),
he can use the template, and save data inputted into the fields.

I am planning to use Spring and Hibernate along with this,
though other suggestions are also appreciated.

Comment: You are asking whether a framework can do what a product offers as a feature. Is like asking whether an engine of a car can offer all -wheel drive.

Comment: @lsiu:ROFLMAO! thats an excellent metaphor!

Comment: I was hoping there was already an existing library, since Eventum seems to have this feature as well. Maybe I'll just to create my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like comments suggests, it is not a framework duty to provide you that kind of fields, it is your duty, as an application developper, and depending upon your requirements, to provide such a feature.